# spring ws dynamic wsdl - no operations, cant change request response element names, what to do?

Tags: spring, soap, wsdl, spring-ws

Problem is, spring ws does not generate operations and others cant generate code over that wsdl. I have it configured as follows:

```
  <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="executeFunnyQuery"
                portTypeName="XYExecuteFunnyQuery"
                locationUri="/ws/"
                targetNamespace="http://www.namespace.eu/sch/xsd/v1/fnmessages"
                requestSuffix="XYExecuteFunnyQuery"
                responseSuffix="ZYExecuteFunnyQuery"
                >
<sws:xsd location="/XYMessagesDictionary/XYExecuteFunnyQuery.xsd"/>
<sws:xsd location="/ZYMessagesDictionary/ZYExecuteFunnyQuery.xsd"/>
```

I understand everything would be fine if i could change element names. But i cant, they are given to me that way and i cant modify them. Response and request element names only differ by their prefix - the first letter, as XYExecuteFunnyQuery is the request and ZYExecuteFunnyQuery is the response. I tried to put full element names to request and response suffix places...does not seem to be doing the trick, sadly.

Can i some howtell without suffix-prefix mambo-jambo to spring that here is my request and here is the response, now generate please! :)

Comment: Hello taivo! I'm facing a similar issue. Did you managed to get it working somehow?

Comment: No unfortunately not. I ended up generating wsdl by hand and serving it as static wsdl.